# show background image in the input text field

Tags: html, css

I have a simple HTML page with background image, and now I'm applying a contact form on this HTML page.

I want to show the background image in the text input field i.e, I want to make input text field transparent. I have use CSS code `background-color:transparent;`, but it doesn't work. I am getting a white background for input text field.

Comment: Plz put you code on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: That code *does* work. You need to supply a *complete* reduced test case for us to tell what is wrong.

Comment: You can try to add a div with a blue background and after that insert and try the transparent input. as @Quentin mention, the codes are working perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
.contact
{
    background: url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ba03773d5fe4b970a7d7fb57a112e932?s=32&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG) no-repeat right center;
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    padding:10px;
}
.contact input[type="text"]
{
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border:1px solid #fff;
    color:#fff;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2ZmFA/

Comment: The image no longer exists :(

Answer (score 1):

This is working on Fiddle:

```
input[type="text"]
{
    background: transparent;
}
```

and withour border if you want by `border: none;`

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3JU3A/)

So your problem must be at another place in code. Add more code and i will update my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" class="textInput"/>
```

**CSS :**

```
.textInput {
 background: transparent;
 background-image: url(Images/textBg.jpg)
}
```

Comment: downVoter, can you please mention the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

You could set the background color to transparent.

```
background-color: rbga(0,0,0,0);
```

alternatively in `css3` you may set the opacity of the whole element:

```
opacity: 0;
```